# Estimating proportion

Tags: conditional-probability, small-sample, ecology

In the context of an ecological study, I am trying to estimate the proportion of a certain mode of transmission on total incident cases of a disease (i.e. "x % of the incident cases transmitted by Z"), for each geographical area. 
The aim is to use this proportion as predictor in a model. I have information on the mode of transmission (except some missings).

The problem is that, while some areas have enough cases for a "reliable" estimation of the proportion (say, n=100), other areas have very few incident cases (say, n=1 or n=2). There are also a few areas with no incident cases at all.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could comment on the options available. Thanks in advance,

Pacov